# Spring Kafka Retry | Error while using RetryTopicConfiguration bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to use spring kafka non blocking retries as mentioned here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic. I have a spring boot application whose pom.xml is below :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.airtel.analytics</groupId>
<artifactId>analytics-store-consumer</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version> 
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>analytics-store-consumer</name> 
<description>analytics-store-consumer</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
    <sonar-jacoco-listeners.version>3.2</sonar-jacoco-listeners.version>
    <jacoco.outputDir>${project.build.directory}</jacoco.outputDir>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/model/**,**/dto/**,**/constants/**,**/exception/**,**/util/**,**/utils/TrafficSource,**/*VO/**,**/*Vo/**,**/mapper/**,**/config/**,**/repository/**,**/application/**,**/controller/**,**/utils/AnalyticsLogTransformerUtils,**/kafka/**</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar-jacoco-listeners.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.airtel.online.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>airtel-commons-homes-logger</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-avro</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
        <artifactId>aerospike-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.airtel.smartapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartapi-logging-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <finalName>analytics-store-consumer</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</sourceDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.avsc</include>
                        </includes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java/</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.airtel.growth.analytics.application.AnalyticsStoreConsumerApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${jacoco.agent.ut.arg}</argLine>
                <!-- Specific to generate mapping between tests and covered code -->
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <!-- test failure ignore -->

                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Prepares a variable, jacoco.agent.ut.arg, that contains the info
                    to be passed to the JVM hosting the code being tested. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-ut-agent</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyName>jacoco.agent.ut.arg</propertyName>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins> 
</build>
```

Also, my retry config file is :

```
@Bean
public RetryTopicConfiguration retryTopicConfiguration(@Value("retryTopicKafkaTemplate") KafkaTemplate<String, AvroProcessedAnalyticsData> template) {
    return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
            .newInstance()
            .listenerFactory("retryKafkaListenerConsumerFactory")
            .exponentialBackoff(30000, 2, 360000)
            .maxAttempts(3)
            .excludeTopics(excludedTopics)
            .setTopicSuffixingStrategy(TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
            .doNotConfigureDlt()
            .notRetryOn(HttpClientErrorException.class)
            .includeTopic(kafkaTopic)
            .create(template);
}

@Bean(name = "retryTopicKafkaTemplate")
public KafkaTemplate<String, AvroProcessedAnalyticsData> retryKafkaTemplate() {
    final Properties configProps = new Properties();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MAX_MS_CONFIG, kafkaReconnectBackoffMaxMilliseconds);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, kafkaReconnectBackoffMilliseconds);
    configProps.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryURLConfig);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, batchSizeConfig);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, lingerConfig);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, sendTimeout);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, bufferConfig);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, sendTimeout);
    configProps.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, false);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientIdConfig);
    KafkaTemplate<String, AvroProcessedAnalyticsData> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(
            new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(configProps));
    kafkaTemplate.setProducerListener(new KafkaProducerListener());
    return kafkaTemplate;
}

@Bean(name = "retryKafkaListenerConsumerFactory")
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, AvroProcessedAnalyticsData>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    final Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, kafkaAutoCommit);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, kafkaAutoCommitInterval);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, kafkaSessionTimeout);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollIntervalMs);
    configProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
    configProps.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryURLConfig);
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AvroProcessedAnalyticsData> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps));
    return factory;
}
```

}

I am getting the below exception:

```html
2022-03-16 20:25:04.395  INFO 59046 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-03-16 20:25:04.410  INFO 59046 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9ebb8b3c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-03-16 20:25:04.421  WARN 59046 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
2022-03-16 20:25:04.426  INFO 59046 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-16 20:25:04.444 ERROR 59046 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:143) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:203) [spring-cloud-context-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:114) [spring-cloud-context-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:71) [spring-cloud-context-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) [spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) [spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) [spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) [spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.airtel.growth.analytics.application.AnalyticsStoreConsumerApp.main(AnalyticsStoreConsumerApp.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.configurationPropertiesBeans(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9ebb8b3c.CGLIB$configurationPropertiesBeans$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9ebb8b3c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bec12067.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
```

Please note that even if I replace the RetryTopicConfiguration bean with @RetryableTopic configuration, then also I am getting the same error.
Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

This actually has nothing to do with the `Retry Topic` feature - there's a mismatch between your `Spring Cloud` and `Spring Boot` versions.

As you can see [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/19/spring-cloud-greenwich-sr4-released), `Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR4 is built upon Spring Boot 2.1.10.RELEASE.`

And as you can see in Spring Cloud's [project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud), for `Spring Boot` versions 2.5.x you should use Spring Cloud `2020.0.x aka Ilford`

<s>It's generally better to only specify Spring Boot's version and let it manage other Spring projects' versions.</s>

EDIT: In Spring Cloud's case, if you can change the Spring Boot version, it's better to let `Spring Cloud` handle versions, as also mentioned in the project's page.

```
<properties>
    <spring.cloud-version>Hoxton.SR8</spring.cloud-version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```